# How to add new language to ABP template?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using free boilerplate (ASP.NET Core MVC & jQuery) from this site https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates

Is it possible to add new language support?

I already add localized .xml file, update 'abplanguages' table in database but it is not working. I'm changing language but text is still in english. The same situation with predefined languages already shipped with boilerplate like 'espanol-mexico' is not working but when I pick 'french' the page is translated.
This is weird because in documentation said it can be done.
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Localization#extending-localization-sources

I wonder is it free template restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. In my case it was incorrect build action property. In VS right click on localization source file: `*.xml file -> Advanced -> Build action: Embedded resource`.

Answer (score 1):

inject `IApplicationLanguageManager` interface and use `AddAsync()` method to add a new language.

```cs
private readonly IApplicationLanguageManager _applicationLanguageManager;


public LanguageAppService(
    IApplicationLanguageManager applicationLanguageManager,
    IApplicationLanguageTextManager applicationLanguageTextManager,
    IRepository<ApplicationLanguage> languageRepository)
{
    _applicationLanguageManager = applicationLanguageManager;
    _languageRepository = languageRepository;
    _applicationLanguageTextManager = applicationLanguageTextManager;
}


protected virtual async Task CreateLanguageAsync(ApplicationLanguageEditDto input)
{
    if (AbpSession.MultiTenancySide != MultiTenancySides.Host)
    {
        throw new UserFriendlyException(L("TenantsCannotCreateLanguage"));
    }

    var culture = CultureHelper.GetCultureInfoByChecking(input.Name);

    await _applicationLanguageManager.AddAsync(
        new ApplicationLanguage(
            AbpSession.TenantId,
            culture.Name,
            culture.DisplayName,
            input.Icon
        )
        {
            IsDisabled = !input.IsEnabled
        }
    );
}

public static class CultureHelper
{
    public static CultureInfo[] AllCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

    public static bool IsRtl => CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft;

    public static bool UsingLunarCalendar = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar.AlgorithmType == CalendarAlgorithmType.LunarCalendar;

    public static CultureInfo GetCultureInfoByChecking(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            return CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(name);
        }
        catch (CultureNotFoundException)
        {
            return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        }
    }
}


public class ApplicationLanguageEditDto
{
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(ApplicationLanguage.MaxNameLength)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(ApplicationLanguage.MaxIconLength)]
    public virtual string Icon { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mapped from Language.IsDisabled with using manual mapping in CustomDtoMapper.cs
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```